# Car rental programming on c#

Tags: c#

I have work on car rental program but i have some problem with rental class.
If i need to checked that this car in array have already rent yet? What should i do.
If have declare array of car stock like this :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Car[] car;
        car = new Car[5];
        Car[] car;
        car = new Car[5];
        car[0] = new Car("Number", "Brand", "Model", Kilometers);
        and go on till car[4]
```

What i I should do to checked the car?

Comment: Think in a object oriented way. When you say car is rented or a car is not rented. This is "is a" relationship. Now you should read about "is a" and "has a" relation.

Comment: To Update the ui after A prooerty of one Car object changed, You Need to implement The INotifyPropertyChanged Interface

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add a `Boolean`  *IsRent* property to you `Car` class, and everytime someone rent the car, change it value to **false**. Somthing like that:

```
  if(car[/here put the index].IsRent==true)//car is not in rent,allow to rent.
 {
    car[/here put the index].IsRent=false;
      //rent the car.
    }


public bool IsRentM
{
  get { return IsRent; }
  set { IsRent = value; }


}
```

Goodluck.

Comment: what get{...} and set{...} I should use in property.

Comment: @Isafe added. if i helped you please mark my answer please :)

Comment: Thank a lot @Slashy it's very helpfull

Comment: inside if maybe "==true"?